# Use Chapter Three, instead of Chapter 3 in css counters

Tags: css

How do I use Chapter “Three”, instead of Chapter “3” in css ordered counters?

The spec states the numbers can be anything css’ list-style-type can be.

Am I out of luck since there is no list-style-type = alpha?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I believe you are, as far as a simple built-in solution.  You'd need to roll your own using a utility like [numbers-to-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words)

Answer (score 0):

Without JS, it is not entirely possible. If you know how many chapters you have, you can manually define your own fixed counter style with `@counter-style`.

```css
main {
  counter-reset: count;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: "Chapter " counter(count, alpha);
}

@counter-style alpha{
  system: fixed;
  symbols: "One" "Two" "Three" "Four" "Five" "Six" "Seven" "Eight" "Nine" "Ten" "Eleven" "Twelve" "Thirteen" "Fourteen" "Fifteen" "Sixteen" "Eighteen" "Ninteen" "Twenty";
  suffix: " ";
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content</span>
  </div>
</main>
```